# How to select cells by function

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA. I coded as the textbook says, but the following error occurred.

**Error message:**

```
Run-time error '5':
Invalid procedure call or argument
```

## What the code is expected to do

1. When `macro1` is executed, a function `getDataRange()` is called.
2. `getDataRange` selects cells `B2:D6`* automatically.

*Typo: B**2**:D6 -> B**3**:D6 (Excludes the first line B2:D2 from the range)

**My code:**

```
Function getDataRange(tableRng As Range) As Range
    Set getDataRange = tableRng("2:" & tableRng.Rows.Count)
End Function

Sub macro1()
    getDataRange(Range("B2:D6")).Select
End Sub
```

**Expected output:**
[image]

## What I tried

1. Run it on a **Mac (Office 2016 for Mac)**
2. Run it on a **virtual Windows** (Parallels Desktop 16 for Mac trial) **(Office 365)**
3. Code in `sheet1`, `ThisWorkBook` and `Module1` on the Mac and the virtual Windows

Could anyone help me solve the issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You'd need `Set getDataRange = tableRng.Rows("2:" & tableRng.Rows.Count)` but note that the rows are relative to the data, so this code would actually select B**3**:D6.

Comment: @Rory You're right. That is my typo. I fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: Are you working with an actual table (`ListObject`)? If so, you might be reinventing the wheel. If you aren't yet working with a `ListObject`, you might consider doing so.

Comment: @Rory I changed my code as you said, and it worked!! Thank you so much. I feel ashamed that it was just a typo ;( I'd like to update my question's status to "solved". I appreciate it if you could post your answer as not a comment but an actual answer. I can vote you and can close this question :) Thank you.

Comment: @BigBen Thank you for your help. I'm sorry but I don't know what `ListObject` is. Anyway the issue was solved. Thank you again :)

Comment: A `ListObject` is just a table: Insert > Table (assuming that Mac is similar to Windows here).

Comment: @BigBen Wow. Cool. I didn't know this function, which mean I was not working with it.

Comment: A `ListObject` has a `DataBodyRange` property, which is the range of the data only without the headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need:

```
Set getDataRange = tableRng.Rows("2:" & tableRng.Rows.Count)
```

but note that the rows are relative to the data, so this code would actually select B**3**:D6

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
Function getDataRange(tableRng As Range) As Range
    'Set getDataRange = tableRng("2: " & tableRng.Rows.Count)
    With tableRng
        Set getDataRange = Range(.Range("a2"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count))
    End With
End Function
```